# Best way to create indexes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have four columns in my table (a, b, c, d) that all of them depend on column (date), so in my queries i have :

```
 select a where date 
 select b where date 
 select c where date 
 select d where date
```

I need to know what's the best way to create indexes for all of them, I have two suggestions :

First suggestion:

```
create i_a on a
create i_b on b
create i_c on c
create i_d on d
create i_date on date
```

Second suggestion:

```
create i_a on a include date
create i_b on b include date
create i_c on c include date
create i_d on d include date
```

Please which one is better to use.

Comment: depends on the overall workload. What other queries run?

Comment: I do group by(a), order by count(a), for b , c , d too

Comment: `CREATE NONCLUSTED INDEX ON Table(Data) INCLUDE(A,B,C,D)`

Comment: @wewesthemenace why use non-clustered index??

Comment: @Mr.香港人, that's just a sample. It depends. I believe testing should be done first before tuning the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Index_Name ON TableName(Date) INCLUDE(A,B,C,D)
```

The column you want to index should be the one used for filtering (`WHERE` clause). You may add an `INCLUDE` to avoid lookups.